# Getting Minimum and Maximum values from a period of time in an HKStatisticsCollectionQuery

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, healthkit

I am trying to collect the minimum and maximum blood oxygen reading over a given period of time from HealthKit on iPhone. I am using an HKStatisticsCollectionQuery with an initialResultsHandler and then using enumerateStatistics and then trying the following code.

```
for stat in stats {
       let min = stat.minimumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit(from: "%"))
       let avg = stat.averageQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit(from: "%"))
       let max = stat.maximumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit(from: "%"))
       output.append(Health.BloodOx(date: stat.startDate, min: min, avg: avg, max: max))
}
```

where stats is an HKStatistics instance and Health.BloodOx is a custom struct.

Any help is appreciated, if you need any more details or code, just let me know!

Thank you so much and have a wonderful day :)

Comment: What is your question?  What happens with the code you have shown?  Does it work?  Does it not work?  If it doesn't work, how doesn't it work?  What output do you get? what is the desired output?  See [Ask]

Comment: @paulw11, I keep getting nil for the minimum and maximum values even when I get an average value. Sorry, I definitely should have included that in the post!

Comment: What `options` are you passing to your `HKStatisticsQuery` ?  Show the code that sets up an performs the query